# Table filter with input box based on table column

Tags: html, json

I have a table,input text box and dropdown with pagination and external json,I need to get search based on selection of dropdown option,once we select dropdown option 'description' and keyup anything on input box then search should  be happens based on description,here is the code below

### HTML

```
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.11.0/bootstrap-table.min.css'>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.12.1/bootstrap-table.js'></script>
<input placeholder="search" type="text"/><select><option>Name</option><option>description</option></select>
  <table id="table"  data-show-header="true" data-pagination="true"
           data-id-field="name"
           data-page-list="[5, 10, 25, 50, 100, ALL]"
           data-page-size="5">
    <thead><tr><th>Name</th><th>stargazers_count</th><th>forks_count</th><th>description</th></tr></thead>
  <tbody>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

### CSS

```
.pagination .active a {
    width: 40px;
    height: 34px;
    -webkit-transform: skew(-21deg);
    position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
    background: red;    
}

.pagination .active span{
-webkit-transform: skew(0deg) !important;
width: 40px !important;
height: 34px !important;


}
.pagination>li>a{
    width: 40px;
    height: 34px;
    -webkit-transform: skew(-21deg);

    background: #fff;
}
.pagination > li.page-pre >a,.pagination > li.page-next >a {
    width: 85px !important;

}
.fixed-table-pagination div.pagination{
margin-right:20px;
}
.pagination-detail{
display:none;
}
.major{
    background-color:green;
}

.critical{
    background-color:orange;
}
```

### JAVASCRIPT

```
<script>

    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost/bspaginationtable/ext-json/members.json", 
        type: "POST",    
        dataType:"json",   
        success: function (response) 
        {
         // var trHTML = '';
          $.each(response, function (key,value) {
             $('table#table TBODY').append('<tr><td>'+value.name+'</td><td>'+value.stargazerscount +'</td><td class="'+ value.forkscount +'"><span>'+value.forkscount +'</span></td><td>'+value.description +'</td></tr>');    
          });

           // $('#table').append(trHTML);
        }   
    });

$(function () {
    $('#table').bootstrapTable({
       // data: data
    });
});
  </script>
```

### members.json

```
[{
            "name": "mango",
            "stargazerscount": 526,
            "forkscount": "critical",
            "description": "fruits"
        },
        {
            "name": "brinjal",
            "stargazerscount": 526,
            "forkscount": "critical",
            "description": "vagetables"
        },
        {
            "name": "grapes",
            "stargazerscount": 526,
            "forkscount": "major",
            "description": "fruits"
        },
        {
            "name": "soap",
            "stargazerscount": 526,
            "forkscount": "major",
            "description": "groceries"
        },
        {
            "name": "dates",
            "stargazerscount": 526,
            "forkscount": "critical",
            "description": "dryfruits"
        },
        {
            "name": "mobiles",
            "stargazerscount": 526,
            "forkscount": "major",
            "description": "electronics"
        },
        {
            "name": "shirt",
            "stargazerscount": 526,
            "forkscount": "critical",
            "description": "clothes"
        }


    ]
```

Comment: `var test = members;` where does `members` come from? It seems to be undefined.

Comment: Hello @ankush,
please remove the code that is not related to your question (i.e. commented code, external libraries, smaller preview of your JSON, ...) and add the error you are getting so we can help you more effectively.

Comment: I have edited my question as per requirement

Comment: Can anyone help me please,thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution from js fiddle and modified it with external json with ajax call with datatables plugin,Just for future reference if anyone need this requirement.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
<style>
.dataTables_paginate  .current {
    width: 40px;
    height: 34px;
    -webkit-transform: skew(-21deg);
    position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;

   border-left:0px  !important;
}
.dataTables td{
border-top:1px solid #ccc;
border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
}
.dataTables_paginate .paginate_button {
    width: 40px;
    height: 34px;
    -webkit-transform: skew(-21deg);
    position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
   border-right:1px solid #000 !important;
   margin-left:0 !important;
}
.dataTables_paginate .previous{
    width:87px;
    background:none;

}
.dataTables_paginate .next{
width:60px;
    background:none;

}
.dataTables_paginate .next{
border-right:0 !important;
}

a:focus {
    outline:0;
    outline-offset:0;
}
.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate {
    float: right;
    text-align: right;
    padding-top: 0.25em;
    margin-right: 5%;
}
.dataTables_paginate>a{
    width: 40px;
    height: 34px;
    -webkit-transform: skew(-21deg);

    background: #red !important ;
}
.dataTables_paginate>a:hover{

}

.major{
   border-top:2px solid green;

}

.critical{
    border-top:2px solid red;
}
.minor{
    border-top:2px solid orange;
}
.critical,.major,.critical-box,.major-box{

padding:3px;
cursor:pointer;
}       
</style>  
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="js/script.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready( function () {
   // $('#example').DataTable();
   var tables = $('#example').DataTable({

   dom : '2<"#add">frtip',
    "language": {
    "paginate": {
      "previous": "<&nbsp;Previous",
      "next": "next&nbsp;>"
    }
  }

})
$('<label/>').text('Search Column:').appendTo('#add')
$select = $('<select/>').appendTo('#add')

$('<option/>').val('All').text('All').appendTo($select);
$('<option/>').val('0').text('name').appendTo($select);
$('<option/>').val('1').text('stargazerscount').appendTo($select);
$('<option/>').val('2').text('forkscount').appendTo($select);
$('<option/>').val('3').text('description').appendTo($select);
$('input[type="search"]').on( 'keyup change', function () {
  var searchValue = $(this).val();
  var columnSearch = $select.val();

  if(columnSearch == 'All'){
    tables.search(searchValue).draw();
  } else {
    tables.columns(columnSearch).search(searchValue).draw();
  }
 });  

$("div").delegate(".major-box", "click", function(){

    var majorValue = $(this).attr('id');

    if(majorValue== 'major'){
    tables.search(majorValue).draw();
  }

});
$("div").delegate(".critical-box", "click", function(){

    var criticalssValue = $(this).attr('id');

    if(criticalssValue== 'critical'){
    tables.search(criticalssValue).draw();
  }

});
} );
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="col-md-6 critical-box" id="critical">critical</div><div id="major" class="col-md-6 major-box">major</div>
</div>
 <table id="example">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>name</th>
                <th>stargazerscount</th>
                <th>forkscount</th>
                <th>description</th>

            </tr>
        </thead>



        <tbody>

        </tbody>
    </table>


</body>
</html>
```

### script.js

```
 $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost/bootstrap-tablefilter/js/members.json", 
        type: "POST",    
        dataType:"json",   
        success: function (response) 
        {
         // var trHTML = '';
          $.each(response, function (key,value) {
             $('table#example TBODY').append('<tr><td>'+value.name+'</td><td>'+value.stargazerscount +'</td><td ><span class="'+ value.forkscount +'">'+value.forkscount +'</span></td><td>'+value.description +'</td></tr>');    
          });

           // $('#table').append(trHTML);
        }   
    });

$(document).ready( function () {

$('#example tbody tr td span.critical').closest('tr').addClass('critialrow');   
$('#example tbody tr td span.major').closest('tr').addClass('majorrow');
/*
$("div").delegate(".critical-box", "click", function(){

    //$('#example').DataTable().destroy().clear();
$('.critialrow').show();
$('.majorrow').hide();
}); 
$("div").delegate(".major-box", "click", function(){
//alert('hi');
$('.critialrow').hide();
$('.majorrow').show();
}); 
*/
});
```

### members.json

```
[{
            "name": "mango",
            "stargazerscount": 526,
            "forkscount": "critical",
            "description": "fruits"
        },
        {
            "name": "brinjal",
            "stargazerscount": 526,
            "forkscount": "critical",
            "description": "vagetables"
        },
        {
            "name": "grapes",
            "stargazerscount": 526,
            "forkscount": "major",
            "description": "fruits"
        },
        {
            "name": "soap",
            "stargazerscount": 526,
            "forkscount": "major",
            "description": "groceries"
        },
        {
            "name": "dates",
            "stargazerscount": 526,
            "forkscount": "critical",
            "description": "dryfruits"
        },
        {
            "name": "mobiles",
            "stargazerscount": 526,
            "forkscount": "major",
            "description": "electronics"
        },
        {
            "name": "shirt",
            "stargazerscount": 526,
            "forkscount": "critical",
            "description": "clothes"
        },
        {
            "name": "dates",
            "stargazerscount": 526,
            "forkscount": "critical",
            "description": "dryfruits"
        },
        {
            "name": "mobiles",
            "stargazerscount": 526,
            "forkscount": "major",
            "description": "electronics"
        },
        {
            "name": "shirt",
            "stargazerscount": 526,
            "forkscount": "critical",
            "description": "clothes"
        },
        {
            "name": "shirt",
            "stargazerscount": 526,
            "forkscount": "critical",
            "description": "clothes"
        },
        {
            "name": "dates",
            "stargazerscount": 526,
            "forkscount": "critical",
            "description": "dryfruits"
        },
        {
            "name": "mobiles",
            "stargazerscount": 526,
            "forkscount": "major",
            "description": "electronics"
        },
        {
            "name": "shirt",
            "stargazerscount": 526,
            "forkscount": "critical",
            "description": "clothes"
        },
        {
            "name": "dates",
            "stargazerscount": 526,
            "forkscount": "critical",
            "description": "dryfruits"
        },
        {
            "name": "mobiles",
            "stargazerscount": 526,
            "forkscount": "major",
            "description": "electronics"
        },
         {
            "name": "mobiles",
            "stargazerscount": 526,
            "forkscount": "major",
            "description": "electronics"
        },
         {
            "name": "mobiles",
            "stargazerscount": 526,
            "forkscount": "major",
            "description": "electronics"
        },
         {
            "name": "mobiles",
            "stargazerscount": 526,
            "forkscount": "major",
            "description": "electronics"
        },
         {
            "name": "mobiles",
            "stargazerscount": 526,
            "forkscount": "major",
            "description": "electronics"
        },
         {
            "name": "mobiles",
            "stargazerscount": 526,
            "forkscount": "major",
            "description": "electronics"
        },
         {
            "name": "mobiles",
            "stargazerscount": 526,
            "forkscount": "major",
            "description": "electronics"
        },
         {
            "name": "mobiles",
            "stargazerscount": 526,
            "forkscount": "major",
            "description": "electronics"
        },
        {
            "name": "shirt",
            "stargazerscount": 526,
            "forkscount": "critical",
            "description": "clothes"
        }


    ]
```